# What is the Water's Edge terrain needed to build the Pirate School Special Building?

Tags: bloons-monkey-city

All I seem to have available is lake and river terrain, but the Pirate School special building says it requires Water's Edge terrain. Where is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Water's Edge" terrain means "land on the edge of a body of water."  Note that it's a **land** tile, not a water tile.  Rivers and Lakes both count as water tiles, so just pick a land tile right next to one of those.